# Literal Hex Values being converted?

Tags: c#, literals, settings

Ok so this code was working fine without issue then all of a sudden it stopped working.

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            Settings.Default.ScaleVendor = 0x0B67;
            Settings.Default.ScaleProductID = 0x555E;

        }
        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            Settings.Default.ScaleVendor = 0x0EB8;
            Settings.Default.ScaleProductID = 0xF000;
        }
        Settings.Default.Save();

    }
```

Now every time Index is changed to 0 its saving the value of 0x0B67 as 2919 and 0x555E as 21854. Same story with index of 1 with different values. 
I don't recall changing anything that has to do with any of this code but for some reason it was accepting the literal hex values and is no longer. Any ideas why it is now converting the values? The setting is as an int at user level.

UPDATE:

The scale was unplugged and thats why it wasn't finding the vendor and product in the Devices Array NOT because the Hex was wrong.

Comment: 0xB67 *is* 2919.  And neither representation is actually used by the computer, which stores everything in binary (101101100111).  Is it the format used in the settings *file* that you are having an issue with?

Comment: and how was it working earlier!

Answer (score 1):

It *never* showed the hex values literally, if your code hasn't changed. Use strings if you want them to show up as-written.

Answer (score 1):

> Now every time Index is changed its saving the value of 0x0B67 as 2919 and 0x555E as 21854.

Those are the same values though. This code:

```
Settings.Default.ScaleVendor = 0x0B67;
```

is *exactly* equivalent to:

```
Settings.Default.ScaleVendor = 2919;
```

In both cases, they're just the integer value 2919 - whether you express that in decimal or hex makes no difference.

Now you may have changed what you're *doing* with the value... but the fact that you happen to use hex for the integer literal will *never* have been relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You are just using value which is written using hex notation. So 0x0B67 and 2919 is the same number. If you want to get number in hex format then:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", Settings.Default.ScaleVendor)
// or
Console.WriteLine(Settings.Default.ScaleVendor.ToString("x"))
```